# Find the value of $\int^1_{-1} x \ln(1^x +2^x +3^x +6^x)\,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Problem :

Find the value of $\int^1_{-1} x \ln(1^x +2^x +3^x +6^x)\,dx$.

My approach :

\begin{align}
&\int^1_{-1} x \ln(1^x +2^x +3^x +6^x)\,dx \\
=& \ln(1^x +2^x +3^x +6^x) \frac{x^2}{2} - \int^1_{-1} \frac{1}{1^x+2^x+3^x+6^x}(2^x\log2+3^x \log3+6^x \log 6 )\frac{x^2}{2} \,dx
\end{align}

[By using by parts]

Is it the correct method of solving this, please suggest, will be of great help, thanks.

Comment: As far as I can see, what you've done is correct, but it won't get you closer to the answer.

Comment: Probably no use for computation, but integrals like this always remind me of the Geometric Calculus (Grossman & Katz, 1972), which has the property $$\int_a^b\log f(x)dx=\log\int_a^b f(x)^{\text{dx}}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1+2^x+3^x+6^x=(1+2^x)(1+3^x)$$

Now $\ln(AB)=\ln A+\ln B$

Apply $\displaystyle\int_p^qf(x)\ dx=\int_p^qf(p+q-x)\ dx$

in $I=\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1x\ln(1+a^x)\ dx=\int_{-1}^1(-x)\ln(1+a^{-x})\ dx=\int_{-1}^1(-x)\{\ln(1+a^x)-x\ln a\}dx$

$\implies\displaystyle I=-I+\ln a\int_{-1}^1x^2\ dx$

Comment: @SalahFatima, $$x\ln(1+2^x+3^x+6^x)=x\ln(1+2^x)+x\ln (1+3^x)$$

Comment: @SalahFatima, Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 7):

$$I=\int_{-1}^0f(x)dx+\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

$$=\int_0^1(f(-x)+f(x))dx$$

$$=\int_0^1(-f(x)+x\ln(6^x)+f(x))dx$$

$$=\ln(6)\int_0^1x^2dx$$

$$=\frac{\ln(6)}{3}.$$

Comment: It appears the OP wants to know if their method was correct.

Comment: By the way, mind me asking, how'd you get the $\ln6$?

Comment: Compute $f(-x)$ and take $6^x$ as denominator.

Comment: Ok, thanks, it's clear to me now.  :D